# WPF Вылетает исключение при обновлении PointCollection для PolyLine

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Вылетает исключение при обновлении PointCollection для PolyLine, что делать?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Привязка в XAML

```
  <Polyline Stroke="OrangeRed" StrokeEndLineCap="Round" StrokeThickness="2" Points="{Binding Path=Points}"/>
```

VM

```
 PointCollection _PP = new PointCollection { new Point(0, 0), new Point(10, 10), new Point(20, 30) };
    public PointCollection PP
    {
        get => _PP;
        set
        {
            _PP = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("PP");
        }
    }
    public RelayCommand Update
    {
        get
        {
            return new RelayCommand(o =>
            {
                Task.Run(() =>
                {
                    while (true)
                    {
                        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
                        PP = new PointCollection { new Point(5, 5), new Point(20, 10), new Point(40, 50) };
                    }
                }
                );
            }
            );
        }
    }
```

Comment: читать ошибку, у вас new PointCollection в отдельном потоке создается. Зачем там Task.Run? попробуйте Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() => { код будет исполнен в UI треде }));

Comment: Если не создавать отдельный поток то заблокируется графический интерфейс.

Comment: PointCollection является Freezable, поэтому вы можете создать его в отдельном потоке, но потом необходимо сделать ему Freeze и только после этого прокинуть его контролу в UI-поток. [Общие сведения об объектах класса Freezable](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/freezable-objects-overview)

Comment: @АндрейNOP, сработало, благодарю

Comment: Отлично, напишите как решили ответом здесь.

Answer (score 1):

Решение подсказал @АндрейNOP

PP.Freeze();

```
public RelayCommand Update
    {
        get
        {
            return new RelayCommand(o =>
            {
                Task.Run(() =>
                {
                    while (true)
                    {
                        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
                        PP = new PointCollection { new Point(5, 5), new Point(20, 10), new Point(40, 50) };
                        PP.Freeze();
                    }
                }
                );
            }
            );
        }
    }
```